# If I restart my game, can I link the new game to the Poke-Bank and re-obtain my Pokemon?

Tags: pokemon-bank

On Pokemon X and Y, I plan on re-setting my game. If I were to put all of my Pokemon into the bank, then reset, could I re-link the bank and the game so I can re-obtain my Pokemon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can deposit your Pokemon in the Bank, restart the game, and withdraw them again. You can even insert a different Pokemon cartridge and access your Banked Pokemon on the new cartridge as well.

Do note that you **cannot keep items** this way - items will be returned to your backpack upon depositing Pokemon in the Bank.

**Reference:**

- [PokemonDB](http://pokemondb.net/spinoff/pokemon-bank)